Why is gcc not aligning structures by default
AFAIK, compilers are supposed to align structures by default.
Why isn't gcc doing it then?
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char r, g, b;
} color_t;

int main() {
    printf("size of color_t: %lu\n", sizeof(color_t));
}

$ gcc test.c -o test
$ ./test
size of color_t: 3

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Note: if I use __attribute__((aligned)) it does get aligned. I'm asking why it's not doing it by default.

Align to what? Chars don't have alignment requirements (on x86 at least).

What is your expectation? What size did you want to be written? What is the output when you use __attribute__((aligned), and how do you use it?

On a different note, the sizeof operator returns a value of type size_t, which technically needs the %zu format to print. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to undefined behavior.

NB:typedef is merely a definition. Instances of color_t will be aligned, typically on a boundary of its largest member type (same goes for all types afaicr)

The compiler is smart enough to align as per strictest alignment requirement of any member. Since you only have character members, there are no alignment requirements.
It could in theory decide to insert padding to align according to the "fundamental alignment requirement" of the target, usually sizeof(int), but it doesn't have to.
If we were to modify the code like this:
typedef struct {
    unsigned short dummy;
    unsigned char r, g, b;
} color_t;

Assuming dummy has an alignment requirement of 2, then the compiler will very likely add a padding byte at the end for a total size of 6, so that an array of structs won't end up with dummy misaligned. It could however use a bigger alignment yet if it wants, it's up to the compiler.
For example if I modify the above example to use uint_fast16_t dummy; telling the compiler I want speed over size, then on a x86_64 I get a struct size of 16 since the word size of 8 bytes is considered fastest. dummy will then take up 8 bytes and there will be 5 padding bytes after r,g,b.

Why would there be padding after uint_fast16_t dummy;, doesn't dummy itself then have 8 bytes?

@ssbssa That's probably the case indeed, will fix - thanks!
